# How to import github repos into Atom editor?

Tags: github, atom-editor

In Atom editor, there is an **import** package that should allow user to import github repos into the Atom, here: https://atom.io/packages/import

I've tried it and it didn't work and gave me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'projectHome' of undefined
```

An issue was also raised but did anyone else have the same problem and know how to resolve this? My system is an `Ubuntu 14.04.1`

**How to import Github repos into Atom editor?**

I've tried to remove `~/.atom/config` file but it doesn't exist:

```
alvas@ubi:~/.atom$ ls
compile-cache  config.cson  nohup.out  packages  storage
```

I've tried removing the `config.cson` and the same error. When i tried to grep for ProjectHome, i got:

```
alvas@ubi:~/.atom$ grep -nRHI projectHome *
compile-cache/coffee/5047aaae22a3f9ac99b5d85d388d780b7e76a729.js:96:      workspace = atom.config.settings.core.projectHome;
compile-cache/coffee/5047aaae22a3f9ac99b5d85d388d780b7e76a729.js:97:      defaultWorkspace = atom.config.defaultSettings.core.projectHome;
packages/import/lib/import-view.coffee:41:    workspace = atom.config.settings.core.projectHome
packages/import/lib/import-view.coffee:42:    defaultWorkspace = atom.config.defaultSettings.core.projectHome
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try, to see if that make the issue go away, a similar solution like [issue 3845](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/3845#issuecomment-59329178):

> Hm, the issue disappeared after I'd remove my `~/.atom/config`.
>   I don't remember if I set something there with hands – guess some of local installed package did something :(

You can see a similar error at [`Atom.project.path` (cannot call path of undefined in test)](https://discuss.atom.io/t/atom-project-path-cannot-call-path-of-undefined-in-test/12041), which points out that not every variable are set.

Comment: do you mean `config.cson`? I don't have a config file in the `.atom` =(

Comment: @alvas you can try and remove (move away) that file (https://atom.io/docs/v0.59.0/customizing-atom#advanced-configuration), just to see if that reset the config enough to get past that error message.

Comment: @alvas could you grep for `projectHome` in any file in your `~/.atom` folder? `cd ~/.atom ; grep -nRHI projectHome *`

Comment: @alvas interesting. I wonder what happen if you were to move the `compile-cache` folder.